# Scanning different types of variables

Tags: c, string, scanf

My assignment is to make a word-hunter game. The user enters the coordinates and the associated word. Coordinates are in the same form as the ones in a chessboard (Ex: `D7 combative`) I'm scanning this as:

```
scanf(" %c%d %s", &ypos, &xpos, word);
```

The problem is, when the user types `exit`, the program should terminate but I scan not only for a string but also for a character, an integer and then for a string. How can I make the program terminate when the input is `exit`?

Comment: scanf first a string and check if its "exit", if not then use sscanf on that string same way as you did with scanf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first `scanf` the input as a string, then check if its the **"exit"** string and exit if it is. If not then with `sscanf` you can get the desired varaibles.

Example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[20];
    char x;
    int y;
    char word[20];

    if (1 != scanf("%19[^\n]", str))
      return printf("Invalid input\n"), 0;

    if (strcmp(str, "exit") == 0)
      return printf("Exiting\n"), 0;

    if (3 != sscanf(str, "%c%d%s", &x, &y, word))
      return printf("Invalid input\n"), 0;

    printf("%c%d %s", x, y, word);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @gokbeykeskin If this answer solved your problem, feel free to accept it.

Comment: Teaching newbie programmers such tricks as `return printf("Invalid input\n"), 0;` does not deserve an upvote (IMHO).

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes you are very true, in all case 0 is return, it is much better to to if else if else it ... else and return 0 at end